# How to change display format of legend in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, format, matlab-figure, legend

I am looking for a way to force the legend entries in a particular format. I following code, they are displayed like

[image]

Instead I want  it like 1e-1,1e-2,1e-3,1e-4, 1e-5.
Is there a way to do this.

**MWE:**

```
sig=[0.1 0.01 0.001 0.0001 0.00001];
for j=1:length(sig)
    for x=1:10
       Cost(j,x) = 2*x+j;
    end 
plot(1:10,Cost(j,:));
end 
legend(strcat('\sigma^2_n=',num2str((sig)')));
set(h,'Interpreter','latex')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should specify that you'd like to use scientific notation when you convert `sig` to a string by passing a [custom format specifier](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html#inputarg_formatSpec) to `num2str`

```
legend(strcat('\sigma^2_n=',num2str(sig.', '%.0e')));
```

[image]

If you want to remove the leading `0` in the exponent, you can remove them with a regular expression

```
S = regexprep(cellstr(num2str(sig.', '%.0e')), '(?<=e[-+])0*', '');
legend(strcat('\sigma^2_n=', S))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice addition. Thank you