# How to force legend entries as power of 10 in MATLAB

Tags: format, matlab-figure, legend

This is an extension of [How to change display format of legend in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074324/how-to-change-display-format-of-legend-in-matlab).

I am looking for a way to force the legend entries in a particular format. In following code, they are displayed like

[image]

Instead I want them in power of 10's. Like $10^{-1},10^{-2}$.
Is there a way to do this?

**MWE:**

```
sig=[0.1 0.01 0.001 0.0001 0.00001];
for j=1:length(sig)
    for x=1:10
       Cost(j,x) = 2*x+j;
    end 
plot(1:10,Cost(j,:));
end 
legend(strcat('\sigma^2_n=',num2str((sig)')));
set(h,'Interpreter','latex')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `log10` `sig` in the `num2str` and prepend the base:

```
sig=[0.1 0.01 0.001 0.0001 0.00001];
for j=1:length(sig)
    for x=1:10
       Cost(j,x) = 2*x+j;
    end 
    hold('on');
    plot(1:10,Cost(j,:));
end 
h=legend(strcat('$\sigma^2_n = 10^{',num2str((log10(sig))'),'}$'));
set(h,'Interpreter','latex','fontsize',16)
hold('off');
```